# Dynamic Array: error free(): invalid next size (fast), Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, arrays

So I was trying to pormpt the user to type in a number, and then store that value in a dynamic array. Here is the code first:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//dynamically grow the array 
void growArray(int *arr, int *size){
    //double the size of the array
    printf("Resizing array\n");
    int *temp = malloc( *size * 2 * sizeof(int)); 
    printf("Malloc was succesfuly\n");
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < *size; i++)
        temp[i] = arr[i]; 

    printf("About to free arr\n");
    printf("arr: %p", arr); 
    printf("temp: %p", temp);
    free(arr);
    arr = malloc( *size * 2 * sizeof(int)); 
    printf("About to change value to arr\n");
    arr = temp; 
    free(temp);
    printf("About to change the value of size\n");
    *size *= 2; 
    printf("New size: %d\n", *size);
}


int main(){

    int *dynamicArr; 
    int *size; 
    *size = 1; 
    dynamicArr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));

    int value, i;
    i = 0; 
    do{
        printf("\nPlease enter in a int value: ");
        scanf("%d", &value); 

        //check if the array needs to be resizesd;
        printf("Checking if size if sufficient\n");
        if (i >= *size)
            growArray(dynamicArr, size);

        if (value != -999){
            printf("Adding value to the array\n");
            dynamicArr[i] = value;
            i ++; 
        }
    }while(value != -999); 

    for (i = 0; i < *size; i++){
        printf("Value of dynamicArr[%d]: %d\n", i, dynamicArr[i]);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

As you can see, I have a bunch of print statements, that I so I can see at what point my program is at, and what it is current doing. So, the program initially works. I am able to add in 8 values successfully (and resize the array 3 times, going from size 1 to size 8). But when I add in my 9 value, it has to resize the array, in which the method growArray() is called. But, for some reason I get the following error:

```
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000e69010 ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Before the error, the printf("About to free arr") works, but printf("arr: %p", arr); isn't called.

I have no idea why this is happening, some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: 1) `int *size; *size = 1;` --> `int size = 1;`.. `growArray(dynamicArr, size);` --> `growArray(dynamicArr, &size);`

Comment: 2) `void growArray(int *arr, int *size)` --> `void growArray(int **arr, int *size)` or `int  *growArray(int *arr, int *size)` (return new array) You can also use `realloc` instead.

Comment: 3) `arr = malloc( *size * 2 * sizeof(int));` occurs memory leak.

Comment: 4) `arr = temp;  free(temp);`  Do not `free` here.--> `arr = temp;`

Comment: There are errors in the code as @BLUEPIXY commented, but you should just use `realloc` to double you array.

Comment: Any reason you don't use the most likely highly optimised standard `realloc`, not even `memcpy`, but some inefficient homebrew code? And C does not support _methods_. You are using _functions_.

Comment: @Olaf This is for a class project, and that is the way our professor showed us how to implement a dynamic array.  I will try and use realloc.

Comment: So either your prof has something in mind he should have told you (maybe an inefficcient way to implement `realloc`) or he is in need of learning the language proberly. I've met both kinds of teachers and a lot of them still have to leave the 1980ies wrt C. As an even more likely variant: you should have listend to the course better and learn about function parameters and pointer (except for the string-literals, there is no array in your code, btw. If your prof can't tell why, it is option 2)

Comment: @Olaf My professor said that the reason why is that, the current focus is on the malloc() function.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Your 3 comment, by removing that line of code, allows my program to work up to 16 values, when it tries to resize at that point, I end up getting a Segmentation error.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.   This line: `printf("Malloc was succesfuly\n");` is not justified because the returned value from `malloc()` has not been tested

Comment: a called function: (in this case: growarray()) cannot change where a pointer in the calling function points unless the address of the array is passed I.E.  the signature should be: `void growArray(int **arr, int *size)` and it should be called via: `growArray( &dynamicArr, size );` and all references to `arr` should be modified to allow for the second `*`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone).

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  I.E.  this: `scanf("%d", &value);`  should be: `if( 1 != scanf("%d", &value) ) { perror( "scanf failed" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  Note: `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are defined in `stdlib.h`

Comment: regarding: `arr = temp; 
    free(temp);`,  arr and temp both point to the same allocated memory, after the assignment.  So passing either of them to `free()` returns the allocated memory to the heap.  do NOT call free at this point in the code

Comment: the posted code contains a memory leak!  near the end of the function: `main()`, the pointer: `dynamicArr` needs to be passed to `free()`.  It is poor programming practice to expect the OS to clean up after sloppy code.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for your comments, I will try to implement your suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code should probably look more like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int size = 1;
    int *dynamicArr = malloc(size * sizeof(*dynamicArr));

    int idx = 0;
    while (1) {
        int value;
        printf("\nPlease enter in a int value: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);

        if (value == -999) {
            break;
        }

        //check if the array needs to be resizesd
        printf("Checking if size if sufficient\n");
        if (idx >= size) {
            size *= 2;
            dynamicArr = realloc(dynamicArr, size * sizeof(*dynamicArr));
        }

        printf("Adding value to the array\n");
        dynamicArr[idx++] = value;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++) {
        printf("Value of dynamicArr[%d]: %d\n", i, dynamicArr[i]);
    }

    free(dynamicArr);
    return 0; 
}
```

Or if you want to stick with your implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//dynamically grow the array 
void growArray(int **arr, int *size){
    //double the size of the array
    printf("Resizing array\n");
    int *temp = malloc( *size * 2 * sizeof(int)); 
    printf("Malloc was succesfuly\n");
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < *size; i++)
        temp[i] = (*arr)[i];

    printf("About to free arr\n");
    printf("arr: %p\n", *arr); 
    printf("temp: %p\n", temp);
    free(*arr);
    printf("About to change value to arr\n");
    *arr = temp;
    printf("About to change the value of size\n");
    *size *= 2;
    printf("New size: %d\n", *size);
}


int main() {
    int size = 1;
    int *dynamicArr = malloc(size * sizeof(*dynamicArr));

    int idx = 0;
    while (1) {
        int value;
        printf("\nPlease enter in a int value: ");
        scanf("%d", &value);

        if (value == -999) {
            break;
        }

        //check if the array needs to be resizesd;
        printf("Checking if size if sufficient\n");
        if (idx >= size) {
            growArray(&dynamicArr, &size);
        }

        printf("Adding value to the array\n");
        dynamicArr[idx++] = value;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < idx; i++){
        printf("Value of dynamicArr[%d]: %d\n", i, dynamicArr[i]);
    }

    free(dynamicArr);
    return 0; 
}
```

BTW, you can use [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/) to copy the whole existing array to the temp array.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I have to use malloc, since that is the current focus of the course (for right now).

Comment: @VineetPatel I added your code with corrections to the answer

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks a lot. But why does it work? Why should have I used a double pointer?

Comment: @VineetPatel The same reason you used a pointer for `size`. You want to changes to be visible to the calling function. You allocate new space in `temp`, which means you get a new address. You then want the calling function to know that the new larger "array" starts there, so you must pass a pointer to the variable which stored the last address, a.k.a `dynamicArr`, so you should pass `&dynamicArr`. only that way you could make changes to the value stored in it (the value, in this case, is the address where the array starts)

Comment: do NOT assign the returned pointer from `realloc()` directly to the target variable.  Because if `realloc()` fails, then the original pointer is lost, resulting in a memory leak.  always use a 'temp' variable for the initial assignment, then check (!=NULL) and only if not NULL then assign tot he target variable.  AND if that pointer is dereferenced when `realloc()` failed, then the program will be trying to access address 0 (from the NULL returned from `realloc()`) which will result in a seg fault event.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems in your original code.

(a) The parameter `arr` is passed to `growArray` by value, so your assignments `arr = malloc(...)` and `arr = temp` are not updating the variable referenced in `main()` only the copy that is local to `growArray`. On the other hand, when you call `free(arr)` you are freeing the buffer pointed to by the variable `dynamicArr` in `main()`. This is the immediate cause of your segfault.

(b) When you assign `arr = temp` then `free(temp);` you leak the buffer you `malloc()`ed just above, then free the buffer you assigned `arr` to point to (leaving it dangling).

```
void growArray(int *arr, int *size){
```

When entering `growArray`, `arr` points to a buffer, A

```
    ...
    int *temp = malloc( *size * 2 * sizeof(int));
```

`temp` is initialized to point to a new buffer, B

```
    ...
    free(arr);
```

the original buffer, A, is freed. The local variable `arr` is now a dangling pointer, as is whatever pointer the caller holds that was passed into this routine by value.

```
    arr = malloc( *size * 2 * sizeof(int));
```

`arr` is set to a freshly allocated buffer, C.

```
    ...
    arr = temp;
```

`arr` is set to alias `temp`, pointing to the buffer B. The buffer C is leaked.

```
    free(temp);
```

Buffer B, pointed to by both `temp` and `arr` is freed. They are both now dangling pointers. When `arr` is later

```
    ...
}
```

Both `tmp` and `arr` go out of scope. The buffers B and C are leaked.

```
int main(){

    int *dynamicArr; 
    int *size; 
    *size = 1; 
    dynamicArr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
```

dynamicArr points to a malloced buffer
        ...
        do{
            ...
            if(...){
                growArray(dynamicArr, size);
                ...
            }

The first time this if condition passes, the value of `dynamicArr` is passed as the argument `arr` to growArray. `growArray` frees the buffer it points to and then allocs and leaks some memory without affecting the local value of `dynamicArr`. `dynamicArr` is now a dangling pointer.

```
        if (value != -999){
            ...
            dynamicArr[i] = value;
```

And then this accesses the dangling pointer and segfaults.